# sharepoint 2007 document library limitations

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I want to know limitations of Sharepoint document library 2007

1) Approximately how many folders we can create in sharepoint document library 2007?
2) How many documents we can store in one document library(means directly in the document library not in folders)?
amd last question is 
3) How many documents we can store in one folder inside document library?

Thanks,
Rushikesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guideline from MS for "acceptable performance" indicates that you should have max. 2000 items in 1 folder (per view), however you can nest the folders.

The max. amount of all items in a document library is 5 million i think.

Answer (score 2):

This Technet article has all you need for MOSS 2007

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787%28office.12%29.aspx

and this is for 2010 : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx